# hbase "Directory is not empty" exception cause region servers to go down

Tags: hadoop, nosql, hbase

I have configured Hbase 1.2.6 with Hadoop 2.7.3 to crawl web via Apache Nutch 2.3.1. From few days, I am stuch in a problem. all region servers (3 nodes) goes down and I got following message in Hbase master log

```
2018-01-08 15:27:06,603 INFO  [main-EventThread] wal.WALSplitter: Archived processed log hdfs://master:9000/hbase/WALs/node1,16020,151540512476
7-splitting/node1%2C16020%2C1515405124767..meta.1515405130768.meta to hdfs://master:9000/hbase/oldWALs/node1%2C16020%2C1515405124767..meta.1515
405130768.meta
2018-01-08 15:27:06,604 INFO  [main-EventThread] coordination.SplitLogManagerCoordination: Done splitting /hbase/splitWAL/WALs%2Fnode1%2C16020%
2C1515405124767-splitting%2Fnode1%252C16020%252C1515405124767..meta.1515405130768.meta
2018-01-08 15:27:06,607 WARN  [ProcedureExecutor-1] master.SplitLogManager: Returning success without actually splitting and deleting all the l
og files in path hdfs://master:9000/hbase/WALs/node1,16020,1515405124767-splitting: [FileStatus{path=hdfs://master:9000/hbase/WALs/node1,16020,
1515405124767-splitting/node1%2C16020%2C1515405124767.default.1515405126022; isDirectory=false; length=83; replication=2; blocksize=134217728; 
modification_time=1515405126033; access_time=1515405126033; owner=hduser; group=supergroup; permission=rw-r--r--; isSymlink=false}]
org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RemoteException(org.apache.hadoop.fs.PathIsNotEmptyDirectoryException): `/hbase/WALs/node1,16020,1515405124767-splitting 
is non empty': Directory is not empty
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSDirDeleteOp.delete(FSDirDeleteOp.java:84)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.delete(FSNamesystem.java:3676)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNodeRpcServer.delete(NameNodeRpcServer.java:953)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocolPB.ClientNamenodeProtocolServerSideTranslatorPB.delete(ClientNamenodeProtocolServerSideTranslatorPB.j
ava:623)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocol.proto.ClientNamenodeProtocolProtos$ClientNamenodeProtocol$2.callBlockingMethod(ClientNamenodeProtoco
lProtos.java)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine$Server$ProtoBufRpcInvoker.call(ProtobufRpcEngine.java:616)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC$Server.call(RPC.java:982)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler$1.run(Server.java:2217)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler$1.run(Server.java:2213)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
        at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1746)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler.run(Server.java:2213)

        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1411)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1364)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine$Invoker.invoke(ProtobufRpcEngine.java:206)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy15.delete(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor19.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
        at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invokeMethod(RetryInvocationHandler.java:187)
        at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invoke(RetryInvocationHandler.java:102)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy15.delete(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocolPB.ClientNamenodeProtocolTranslatorPB.delete(ClientNamenodeProtocolTranslatorPB.java:490)
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor14.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
:
```

What is the problem ?

Comment: Probably because of this https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HBASE-14729